# É possível integrar o PayPal no meu site, sem que o usuário faça o login ou crie uma conta?

Tags: php, html, pagamento-online, e-commerce

Estava procurando e lendo a respeito, mas o que mais vejo é colocarem apenas o botão de pagar com PayPal, que requer que quem esta comprando efetue o login na Paypal. Tem como fazer isso, alguma luz de código exemplo? Porque vi que é possivel, mas onde posso encontrar detalhes dessa implementação?
Agradeço desde já

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, utilizando a [API Direct Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPDirectPayment/)

[image: Esquema do dirrect payment]

Answer (score 0):

Isso é chamado de `Checkout transparente`. No caso do Paypal, esse serviço é oferecido através do [PayPal Payment Pro](https://www.paypal.com/br/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro).

Além do PayPal, existem outras empresas que oferecem essa serviço, como o [Moip](https://labs.moip.com.br/integracao/transparente/) e o [PagSeguro](https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/receba-pagamentos.jhtml#checkout-transparent).

Importante mencionar que utilizando esse tipo de pagamento, existe uma atenção especial em relação a segurança da sua aplicação. Como por exemplo, um certificado SSL e disponibilizar a página de checkout apenas através de https.